# Plot raster in R without colour scale

Tags: r, plot, raster

I have a raster, "cov.all". If I plot this in R using `plot(cov.all)` I get this image:

[image: cov.all]

How can I can I plot the raster without the colour scale?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Is this from the `raster` package? did you try `plot(cov.all, legend = FALSE)`?

Comment: Please make your situation reproducible, i.e. provide us with the data and the code needed to mimic your situation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for more tips on how to do this.

Comment: Yes it is. I hadn't tried that as I didn't see that option in the documentation. It works - thanks for your help!

Comment: @si_2012, you can write that as the answer and mark it as answered so that the question remains answered.

Answer (score 3):

From arun, above, the solution to this is `plot(cov.all, legend=FALSE)`